# Git is throwing a readlink error when I try and add files to my repo

Tags: node.js, github, digital-ocean

Good Evening everyone,
When I try and add files to my git repo I am getting an error. I have run git init. I did clone a repo into the filesystem and then removed the remote. My goal is I'm just trying to add the files of my server to a different repo on github. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

```js
root@portfolio-test:/# sudo git add .
error: readlink("proc/10/exe"): No such file or directory
error: unable to index file 'proc/10/exe'
fatal: adding files failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did clone a repo into the filesystem and then removed the remote

First, make sure you clone the rpeository *not* as root, by as a regular user.

Then you should go to (cd /path/to) that repository folder, and do:

```
git remote set-url origin https://url/new/remote/repository
git push
```

Right now, you are trying to git add from /, the root folder of your system.
That won't work, as there are too many files, including system files which won't be able to be added.

- Don't work as root
- Do work in your cloned repository folder, not /.